# I want to complete the translation app by passing only a part of the selected string in the front-end to the back-end

Tags: reactjs, node.js

### 【Summary】

Now, I’m trying to make an app for translation using DeepL API. The screenshot below is completed. When you click on the arrow, you can translate an English sentence into a Japanese sentence. Of course, any languages that DeepL provides are available.

[image]

The specification is that the user selects the name of the languages, including the language code. However, the DeepL API needs the string of the language code, not the language name, when translating.

**How should I fix the codes to give the string of the language code to the server.js in the back-end, while the user selects the language name in the front-end?**

#### Full App.js

```
import TextBox from "./components/TextBox";
import Arrows from "./components/Arrows";
import Button from "./components/Button";
import Modal from "./components/Modal";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [inputLanguage, setInputLanguage] = useState("English");
  const [outputLanguage, setOutputLanguage] = useState("Japanese");
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(null);
  const [languages, setLanguages] = useState(null);
  const [textToTranslate, setTextToTranslate] = useState("");
  const [translatedText, setTranslatedText] = useState("");

  const getLanguages = async() => {
    const response = await axios("http://localhost:8000/languages");
    setLanguages(response.data);
  }

  const translate = async () => {
    const data = {
      textToTranslate, outputLanguage, inputLanguage
    }
    const response = await axios("http://localhost:8000/translation", {
      params: data,
    });
    setTranslatedText(response.data);
  }

  console.log("translatedText", translatedText);

  console.log("languages", languages);

  useEffect(() => {
    getLanguages();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setInputLanguage(outputLanguage);
    setOutputLanguage(inputLanguage);
  }

  console.log("showModal", showModal);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {!showModal && <>
        <TextBox
          selectedLanguage={inputLanguage}
          style="input"
          setShowModal={setShowModal}
          textToTranslate={textToTranslate}
          setTextToTranslate={setTextToTranslate}
          setTranslatedText={setTranslatedText}
        />
        <div className="arrow-container" onClick={handleClick}>
          <Arrows />
        </div>
        <TextBox
          selectedLanguage={outputLanguage}
          style="output"
          setShowModal={setShowModal} 
          translatedText={translatedText}
        />
        <div className="button-container" onClick={translate}>
          <Button />
        </div>
      </>}
      {showModal && <Modal 
        setShowModal={setShowModal}
        languages={languages}
        chosenLanguage={showModal === "input" ? inputLanguage : outputLanguage}
        setChosenLanguage={showModal === "input" ? setInputLanguage : setOutputLanguage}
      />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### 【Supplementary information】

#### 1. Coding and steps

I uploaded the entire codes and the details on GitHub.

- [all](https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/tree/developer_3)
- [App.js](https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/blob/developer_3/src/App.js)
- [Modal.js](https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/blob/developer_3/src/components/Modal.js)
- [steps](https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/commits/developer_3)

#### 2. screen with error

After doing [this step](https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/commit/d7b2909f8bd2a913f17e3ab8afc17e9552967193), you can respectively see the errors in the front-end(`localhost:3000`).

#### errors in front-end

[image]

#### 3. deepl-node

I use the `translate()` that the deepl-node has, in order to translate with DeepL API. The official document on its use is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepl-node#translating-text).

It explains that the source language and the target language to translate should be specified by language code, not by language name.

#### 4. Bring the data of DeepL API into my app

[image]

#### 5. server.js

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

import * as deepl from "deepl-node";

const PORT = 8000;
const axios = require("axios").default;
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server running on PORT " + PORT));

app.get("/languages", async(req, res) => {
  const authKey = process.env.DEEPL_API_KEY; // Replace with your key
  const translator = new deepl.Translator(authKey);
  const sourceLanguages = await translator.getSourceLanguages();

  try {
    res.status(200).json(sourceLanguages.map(lang => `${lang.name} (${lang.code})`));
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({message: err});
  }
});

app.get("/translation", async(req, res) => {
  const {textToTranslate, outputLanguage, inputLanguage } = req.query;
  const authKey = process.env.DEEPL_API_KEY; // Replace with your key
  const translator = new deepl.Translator(authKey);

  try {
    (async () => {
      const result = await translator.translateText(textToTranslate, inputLanguage, outputLanguage);
      console.log(result.text);
      res.status(200).json(result.text);
    })();
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({message: err});
  }
});
```

Comment: you should provide more of your codes here, instead of linking to GitHub. Specifically, your frontend code like the full `App.js` file since your error looks like you are not configuring the right value to be stored in the state variable for your selected language. It also looks like you have errors configuring axios, so you should show your axios config file too. Your backend code does not seem to be the issue, so remove the files for backend and focus more on sharing your **frontend folder structure** and codes in the relevant files relating to the error.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your advice. Now, as you said to me, I omitted my comment related to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three main issues with your code:

**1) You did not define the correct entry point for starting your backend**

I checked your **backend** folder and you configured your `package.json` to start the server using `index.js`, but you have no such file - your file is named `server.js`.

You also have no `start` command, so there is no way to start your server, hence no way for your frontend to make the API calls.

**Fix**: `package.json` in your backend folder should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "deepl-node": "^1.10.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

You can then start your API either with `npm run dev` (or `yarn` if that's what you're using), this will use `nodemon` to start your server, which will then be accessible via `http://localhost:8000/`.

Only then will your frontend be able to connect to the API.

**2) You are not using `axios` correctly for your requests on the frontend**

You need to specify what kind of request you are making i.e `POST`, `GET`, etc. Right now, you are using axios like this:

```
await axios(<<URL>>)
```

But it should be:

```
await axios.get(<<URL>>) //for GET requests
```

So, you need to correct **ALL your axios requests** and it should fix the Axios and Network errors.

You can read more on how to use axios [here](https://axios-http.com/).

**3) The warnings relate to the `input` elements in your `SelectDropDown.js`.**

You defined a `value` prop on the `input` element without an event handler. I get what you are trying to achieve, but `input` may not be the right element to use for a custom dropdown. You can use a different element, maybe `<span>`.

Try this:

```
const SelectDropDown = ({ selectedLanguage, style, setShowModal }) => {
  return (
    <div className="select-drop-down" onClick={() => setShowModal(style)}>
      <span>{selectedLanguage}</span>
      <div className="down-arrow">
        <svg
          focusable="false"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default SelectDropDown;
```

That should fix the warnings as well.

> **UPDATE:**
>
> In case you encounter a similar issue, OP had more errors in their
> frontend/backend code, and they were all fixed by [this PR I made](https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/pull/1).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your advice again, Airah.
I fixed the three issues below. You can see the differences in my GitHub repository. 

https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/commit/04c6bb6767fa48c2dd2a7b44c6fc5fc9ff3acfa7

Comment: and the errors you were facing have been resolved, correct? if so, you can accept the answer, or let me know if you're facing any other issues @echizenya_yota

Comment: Thank you. I am still facing the same issue. I can see ```Network Error Axios Error``` on my screen, although I fixed the three main issues. 

Furthermore, I can see the error of ```DeepLError: texts parameter must be a non-empty string or array of non-empty strings at appendTextsAndReturnIsSingular``` on my Mac terminal too after launching the backend using ```nodemon server.js```.

Comment: The Network error is still happening because your backend did not start successfully. And the backend error is relating to how you're using the `deepl-node` package for your backend. You should check whether you have correctly defined your API key in a `.env` file and that you are using the right methods. You can also add a screenshot of the full error to your question inspect further @echizenya_yota

Comment: I correctly defined my API Key because I could bring the language data of the DeepL API into my app in [the previous step](https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/commit/bf4ea870d4ff8db2900b29440b35e2c933064a2d). If you look at No.4 in the original post, you can see some languages in the screen.

Comment: Or rather, I would say that there are some issues at the 38 line in the server.js, especially, the second argument and the third argument. This is because when you use the ```translateText()``` of the [deepl node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepl-node#translating-text) to translate an original text, you need the language codes. 

However, the ```inputLanguage``` and the ```outputLanguage``` in the server.js that I defined as a second argument and a third argument don’t specify the language code respectively, and I don’t know how to specify by using variables.

Comment: So, other than No.4, I added No.5 to check whether or not my codes in the server.js are valid.

Comment: @echizenya_yota I have fixed your app, check this Pull request on your repo to see what was causing your errors: https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/pull/1

Comment: Thank you for checking my codes. Actually, I haven’t yet used the Pull request in GitHub. Now, I’m learning how to use it and checking your codes there to fix 

So afterward, I will accept your answer and upvote it. I would like you to wait me for a while until then. I'm going to leave a comment again here.

Comment: Thanks to your [commits](https://github.com/echizenyayota/deepl-node_translation_20231017/commit/a689092f8dfd4c615d559772e2f833027a5778fa), I could fixed my errors and I completed my translation app.  Now, it is available on ```localhost:3000```.

Of course, I want to upvote your original solution, but I haven’t had enough reputation to upvote. According to stack overflow, I need at least 15 reputations to upvote but I haven’t reached them. Anyway, I want to thank you for helping me out!

Comment: I'm glad the app is done now! It was nice interacting with you and working through the issues, I was also able to try my hands on `deepl-node` so thank you too @echizenya_yota